# Exception when referencing a resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, reference, resourcedictionary, pack-uri

My Solution consists of the following projects:

- ServiceTools.Com
- ServiceTools.UI (Startup)
- ServiceTools.UI.Controls
- ServiceTools.UI.Themes

In UI.Controls I've created a custom Button Control which derives from Button. This Custom button should use a ResourceDictionary which is located in *ServiceTools.UI.Themes.Buttons.Default.xaml*

So ServiceTools.UI.Controls references ServiceTools.UI.Themes and uses

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ServiceTools.UI.Themes;component/Buttons/Default.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I try to use the Dictionary IntelliSense is suggesting all my Brushes (at least outside the Triggers section).
When I start debugging the application it crashes immediately with a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException (

> Inner Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceTools.UI.Themes, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"ServiceTools.UI.Themes, Culture=neutral"

May anyone tell me why this is not working as expected?

**Edit 1:**

For test purpose I added a new ResourceDictionary inside ServiceTools.UI.Controls and referenced it as:

```
[...] Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes/Default.xaml"[...]
```

but with the same result - Exception that says "cannot locate resource".

Comment: Which Microsoft Visual Studio version are you using, and which .Net Framework?

Comment: VS 2015 Enterprise @ .Net 4.6

Comment: Probably you need to set the output directory for your binaries to the same directory for all projects.